# How to absolutely position element against page rather than floated parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm writing CSS for a page where, unfortunately, I cam very limited in what I can change. The situation I've got is that a div that I want to absolutely position in the top left corner of the page is inside a div style `float: left;`

```
<style>
.float {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="float">
    <div class="absolute">
    </div>
</div>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, this works just fine. In Explorer and Safari, the absolutely positioned div is pushed down by the margin on the float; I can't make it go to the top corner.

Any ideas how to solve this? I'm limited to CSS only - no changing the HTML, no javascript.

Comment: It would be better to post a live demo of this. You'll need `position: relative` on the `.float` div, but that's not the end of the story.

Comment: If you don't want it to receive the margin-top: 100px (and I'm assuming you can't delete that line) can you simply try adding your own margin-top: 0 !important; (try without the !important first)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is the absolute positioned child will be placed relative to the nearest positioned parent. So, try:

```
body { position: relative; }
```

Look into the floated div and see what `position` is set to after you float.

Comment: Thank you! This made Chrome and Firefox behave the same as Explorer and Safari, so I was able to fix the issue with a negative top position on the absolutely positioned div. Not the neatest, but it works so I'm happy!